# How do you store multiple rows of data for a key and also maintain good normalization practices?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

Imagine in one data table, you had a person and their exam scores for different categories (math/science/english) and for different exam numbers (1, 2). Like so:

| Person | Math | Science |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 88 | 76 |
| Bob | 90 | 99 |
| Joe | 48 | 46 |
| Joe | 70 | 69 |

Would it be better to normalize this table by expanding column-wise (so, we have a math1 and science1 column and a math2 and science 2 column, or just adding a row_id column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a many-to-many (m:m) relationship, while dancing around implementing it. Your m:m is between entities Persons and Subject (categories), each of which becomes a table. You then resolve the m:m by creating a third table - call it exams.

```
create table persons ( person_id integer generated always as identity 
                     , name  text 
                     -- other attributes strictly about each person
                     , constraint persons_pk
                                  primary key (person_id) 
                     ) ; 

create table subjects ( subject_id integer generated always as identity 
                      , name  text 
                      , description text
                      -- other attributes strictly about each subject 
                      , constraint subjects_pk
                                   primary key (subject_id) 
                      ) ; 
                     
create table exams ( person_id   integer  
                   , subject_id  integer
                   , exam_date   date   
                   , score       integer
                   -- other attributes strictly about each exam
                   , constraint exams_pk
                                primary key (person_id, subject_id,  exam_date) 
                   , constraint exams2persons_fk
                                foreign key (person_id)
                                references persons(person_id)
                   , constraint exams2subject_fk
                                foreign key (subject_id)
                                references subjects(subject_id)                                
                   ) ;
```

Note: the above is still a very simplified example but should provide guidance for resolving this type design issue. See fiddle for [worked example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad205802cef36688c9e8fea713341d8b).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the columns into math1, science1, math2, science2, etc. would not be "normalizing." It's an example of repeating groups, which is usually considered a violation of First Normal Form.

You said each of the multiple rows per person corresponds to a different exam. How would you know which exam each row goes with? Why not add a column `exam_no`?